# Issues in placing cross-shaped ships in a matrix with limitations

Tags: python, matrix, logic

i'm having huge issues in finding a way to make my code work: i need a python script that given a file of triple (width, height, dumping_doors) representing the dimensions of a spaceship that is trying to land in a city filled with buildings. The city is a black png image and the buildings are colored squares/rectangles in it. I need this script to return a list of 'i' boolean representing if the spaceship at index 'i' can find a place to land and open the dumping doors on each side of the spaceship. So the ship needs a cross-like space to land, i have a file with the coords of every building in the city, but i'm not using it because i thought it was computationally better to just visit the png and looking for a clear space, but i can't make it work. What am i doing wrong?

following the part of my code that doesn't work:

...

```
for spaceship in spaceships:
        can_it = can_land(img_matrix, spaceship, max_width, max_height)
        landing_result.append(can_it)

    return landing_result

def can_land(img_matrix, spaceship, max_width, max_height):
    w, h, d = spaceship
    # Scorro i pixel lungo la matrice immagine, considerando le dimensioni dell'astronave
    for y in range(max_height - h + 2*d + 1):
        for x in range(max_width - w + 2*d + 1):
            if is_space_free(img_matrix, x, y, w, h, d):
                mark_spaceship(img_matrix, x, y, w, h, d)
                return True

    return False

def mark_spaceship(img_matrix, x, y, w, h, d):
    for i in range(h + 2 * d):
        for j in range(w + 2 * d):
            img_matrix[y + i - d][x + j - d] = (255, 255, 255)


def is_space_free(img_matrix, x, y, w, h, d):
    max_height = len(img_matrix)
    max_width = len(img_matrix[0])

    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x + w + d > max_width or y + h + d > max_height:
        return False

    i = -d
    j = -d
    flag = True
    while (i < h + d) and (j < w + d):
        if img_matrix[y+i][x+j] != (0,0,0):
            return False
        if flag and j+1 != 0:
            j +=1          
        else:
            i+=1
        

    return True
```

...

Thank y'all for your time!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.